# How to drop all InfluxDB databases?

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to drop all of the InfluxDB databases except the _internal one as I do not want to do this every time manually, however, this is not supported directly from [influxdb](https://community.influxdata.com/t/drop-all-databases-except-the--internal-database/1662). I was considering writing a shell script for this, however, I was not able to list all of the databases in order to pipe them to the `DROP DATABASE <db_name>` command. Every suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I went for a short python script using [influxdb](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) -

```py
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
import os

influx_host = os.getenv('INFLUX_HOST', 'localhost')
db_client = InfluxDBClient(host=influx_host)

db_list = db_client.get_list_database()

for db in db_list:
    db_client.drop_database(db['name'])
```

Comment: This solution helps me delete 7,000 plus db's. --Thanks.